# Ajax refresh messes up jqModal functionality

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqmodal

I am trying to use jqModal in my .net/mvc app to do simple jquery modal popups.  I have a table where I list out records and have an "edit" button to popup a modal dialog to do the edits.  When I submit, I hide the modal popup and refresh the table listing below using the .ajax() method.

However, now when I click on the "edit" page, jqModal isn't firing and instead it just goes to my edit page directly (rather than the modal popup).

I've tried to re-inject the jqModal scripts after the ajax callback but that doesn't work either.  Any help appreciated!!!

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: "HomePage/ViewTimelineFeatures",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result) {
            $("myDiv").html(result);
            // Now re-initialize jqModals here doesn't work...
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add in the triggers again after updating the html.  I had this exact same problem.

WHen you call $("#blah").jqmodal... it sets up the trigger on the .jqmodal class to load your content in the modal.  I'm assuming you're loading these with ajax?  So something like:

```
$("#someDiv").jqModal({ajax:'@href'});
```

I'm a bit confused by your above ajax code, is this doing a save of the item you've edited?  This wouldn't normally be a get, but a put.  Anyway, it looks like you render out the table with the updated data and replace the existing one.
After

> $("myDiv").html(result);

You need

```
$("#someDiv").jqmAddTrigger(".jqModal");
```

To add the triggers again on your edit links (assuming you used .jqModal in the first place)  If you want to paste in some html/ajax code I can verify this.